# Setting Claims outside GetAuthenticationStateAsync does not affect <Authorized> tags

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have wiered Blazor-server behavoir. I have custom auth provider. It works fine when Roles are asigned inside `GetAuthenticationStateAsync` method. But if I exctract assignment to a method, then <**Authorized**> tag inside Components does not work, despite `@content.User.Identity` contains every assigned claims.
Here what I have inside my `GetAuthenticationStateAsync` method in my `CustomAuthenticationStateProvider`:

```
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var username = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<String>("user");
            var token = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<String>("token");

            var isValid = Utils.Utils.Instance.CheckUserToken(username, token);

            ClaimsIdentity identity;

            if (isValid)
            {
                Users u = Utils.Utils.Instance.GetUserByToken(token);

                // IF I EXTRACT FOLLOWING CODE INTO A METHOD, THEN <Authorized> TAG WILL NOT WORK
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                   {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
                   }, "Password");


                if (Roles.IsAdmin(u.RoleMask))
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
                }
                if (Roles.IsAgent(u.RoleMask))
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "agent"));
                }
                if (Roles.IsClub(u.RoleMask))
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "club"));
                }
                if (Roles.IsPlayer(u.RoleMask))
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "player"));
                }
                // ----------------- end of extraction ----------------------------------------

            }
            else
            {
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            }

            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
        }
```

And here is how I extract method with claims assignment:

```
private ClaimsIdentity SetIdentity(Users u)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, u.UserName)
            });

            if (Roles.IsAdmin(u.RoleMask))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
            }

            if (Roles.IsAgent(u.RoleMask))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "agent"));
            }

            if (Roles.IsClub(u.RoleMask))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "club"));
            }

            if (Roles.IsPlayer(u.RoleMask))
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "player"));
            }

            return identity;
        }
```

**Question**: Why assignment inside method body works for <**Authorized**> tag, and why it does not work for <**Authorized**> tag when it is extracted to a method?

Comment: You shouldn't create a custom AuthenticationStateProvider for the mere purpose of adding claims into the ClaimsPrincipal object. You've got it all wrong. And your code is not complete, so not much can be said about it.

Comment: @enet. I do not merge. I have my own Provider. What I've got all wrong? Can you clarify? And in which cases I should do CustomProvider?

Comment: here's an answer to your question. Visit this link and ask as many question as you like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62529029/customizing-the-authenticationstateprovider-in-blazor-server-app-with-jwt-token